# Azure Cognitive Services - Face API Response: Reserved Fields or Bugs?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

In the Azure Cognitive Services Face API (see e.g. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face), the following response fields never seem to trigger:

1. headPose:pitch (reserved field)
2. foreheadOccluded
3. eyeOccluded

Am I misusing these, or is there a plan for them, or is there no plan to activate them?

Comment: PS Moderators: I know that this is service specific, but Azure is making use of stackoverflow for technical questions. Also: If the question is unclear, please suggest constructive improvements rather than simply downvoting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the API documentation [here](https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236):

- For the `headPose`, it says:

EDIT 13/06/2019: doc was saying

> HeadPose's pitch value is a reserved field and will always return 0

Now changed to:

> headPose: 3-D roll/yaw/pitch angles for face direction.

- For the `foreheadOccluded` value, I successfully got `true` value in the following test, where there is a cap on the head (sorry for the sample, did not find anything else quickly!):

  - URL: `https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=occlusion`
  - Content sent: `{ "url": "https://www.knijff.com/markmatters/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Trump-Red-Hat.jpg" }`

[image: Sample for forehead occluded]

Reply received:

```
[{
  "faceId": "e6ae42a6-b008-4859-9bf5-1ae22e4b71a7",
  "faceRectangle": {
    "top": 118,
    "left": 212,
    "width": 276,
    "height": 276
  },
  "faceAttributes": {
    "occlusion": {
      "foreheadOccluded": true,
      "eyeOccluded": false,
      "mouthOccluded": false
    }
  }
}]
```

- For the `eyeOccluded` value, I successfully got `true` and `false` values in the following test where the same person appears 2 times, one with a rectangle over the eyes:

  - URL: `https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=false&returnFaceAttributes=occlusion`
  - Content sent: `{ "url": "https://jov.arvojournals.org/data/Journals/JOV/933685/i1534-7362-14-13-14-f09.png" }`

[image: Sample for eyes occluded]

Reply received (please note that 1st face is the right one):

```
[{
  "faceId": "4c2eb52e-2fd4-456c-bdae-694df1adc571",
  "faceRectangle": {
    "top": 204,
    "left": 683,
    "width": 297,
    "height": 297
  },
  "faceAttributes": {
    "occlusion": {
      "foreheadOccluded": false,
      "eyeOccluded": false,
      "mouthOccluded": true
    }
  }
}, {
  "faceId": "5b9dc938-e6cf-4fe9-8e6c-8649fef44e7a",
  "faceRectangle": {
    "top": 213,
    "left": 107,
    "width": 275,
    "height": 275
  },
  "faceAttributes": {
    "occlusion": {
      "foreheadOccluded": false,
      "eyeOccluded": true,
      "mouthOccluded": false
    }
  }
}]
```

Comment: Nicolas R - looks like headPose pitch can now be non-zero?! :) They don't really advertise such facts very well....

Comment: Yes, good point! the doc says now `headPose: 3-D roll/yaw/pitch angles for face direction.`. Will edit my reply